# Endnotes and Footnotes in the same document?

Tags: footnotes, endnotes

Is there a chance to create footnotes for a `\chapter` and endnotes for another chapter in the same `\scrbook`-based document? The endnotes should appear directly after the chapter.

Comment: There is a chance for anything, but please post a minimal working example to help us help you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple sample how to turn footnotes locally into endnotes. It simply `\let`s footnotes to endnotes and vice versa.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\ofootnote\footnote

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foonote 1}
Test\footnote{Quack}. This is a test\footnote{Test}.
\let\footnote\endnote
\chapter{Endnote}
Test\footnote{Quack}. This is a test\footnote{Test}.
\let\footnote\ofootnote
\chapter{Footnote 2}
Test\footnote{Quack}. This is a test\footnote{Test}.
\clearpage\theendnotes
\end{document}
```